# Elegant way to obtain combinations for a list of iterables

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a list of iterable objects, and I'm interested in obtaining all lists that consist of 0 or 1 items from each iterable (order is unimportant, so it's combinations not permutations I seek).

I have a really inelegant implementation that I've posted below.

I'm convinced there's a far more elegant way to do this, possibly with the `itertools` module, but I can't come up with anything. Any advice?

---

```
import itertools


def all_subsets(ss):
    subset_lens = range(0, len(ss) + 1)
    list_of_subsets = map(lambda n: itertools.combinations(ss, n), subset_lens)
    return itertools.chain.from_iterable(list_of_subsets)


list_of_iterables = [["A1"], ["B1", "B2", "B3"], ["C1", "C2"]]

all_possibilities = itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.product(*subset)
                                for subset in all_subsets(list_of_iterables))

# Visual representation of the desired result
for eg in all_possibilities:
    print eg
```

Result:

```
()
('A1',)
('B1',)
('B2',)
('B3',)
('C1',)
('C2',)
('A1', 'B1')
('A1', 'B2')
('A1', 'B3')
('A1', 'C1')
...
```

Comment: Are you simply interested in displaying the results or do you also want the combinations stored?

Comment: @Edgar, I'll be doing something else with the results that is out of the scope of this question, so I need to store, not print. The visual representation is just to aid the explanation of my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[filter(None, comb) for comb in itertools.product(*[[None] + it for it in list_of_iterables])]
```

This makes a couple simplifying assumptions.  If your iterables contain values that aren't true in a boolean context, you'd have to use a more complicated `filter`.  If  your iterables aren't lists, you'd have to use `itertools.chain` instead of `[None] + it`.

Comment: My iterables are not lists (I`ll use `chain`), but I have implemented `__nonzero__` on each object within. This works wonderfully, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with...

```
data = [["A1"], ["B1", "B2", "B3"], ["C1", "C2"]]
data = [[None] + x for x in data]
data = sorted(filter(None, x) for x in itertools.product(*data))
for result in data:
    print result
```

Output:

```
()
('A1',)
('A1', 'B1')
('A1', 'B1', 'C1')
('A1', 'B1', 'C2')
('A1', 'B2')
('A1', 'B2', 'C1')
('A1', 'B2', 'C2')
('A1', 'B3')
('A1', 'B3', 'C1')
('A1', 'B3', 'C2')
('A1', 'C1')
('A1', 'C2')
('B1',)
('B1', 'C1')
('B1', 'C2')
('B2',)
('B2', 'C1')
('B2', 'C2')
('B3',)
('B3', 'C1')
('B3', 'C2')
('C1',)
('C2',)
```

Comment: Heh, exactly the same as mine, and we posted at almost the same instant!  Convergent thinking!

Comment: Or is it the zen of Python? "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."